# can somebody please Identify this queen ant?

Tags: species-identification

[image: please identify this queen]

hi, i found this queen in France and i want to know if it is a species i can take back home to England. i cant identify her since the only queens I've ever kept are Lasius Niger so i would like some help please!!

Comment: Please don't. It is never ever a good idea to import insects. The species is irrelevant, even a native species can be genetically different.

Comment: Oh, ok, i had no idea. im still kinda new at ant keeping. I only go to France for the Summer holidays so will i have to let her go?

Comment: that would be my advise, yes.

Comment: +1 to RHA's suggestion, but it isn't just genetic difference: insects (and any other animal or plant) can carry disease as well.

Comment: Just to add: it is often not only a bad idea *biologically* to carry insects to new locations (even different habitats *within* the same state/region/country), it is also often times **illegal**. Glad to hear you're releasing it where you found it :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 main families in France. Formicinae, Dolichoderinae, Myrmecinae ans Ponerinae. This is a an ant in the subfamily Formicinae because it is large and has only one segment between the thorax and the abdomen. You can deduce that because the thorax and the abdomen seem very close. This particular ants is a queen of the genus Formica (wood ants) from the general aspect. The presence of wings indicate this is a reproductive individual and because the eyes are small compared to the rest of the head it is a female. The color and the general shape and the size would allow any trained observer to identify the genus Formica, although no formal criteria can be seen on this picture. Formal criteria require inspection of the funicula, a part of the antenna, which cannot be seen on this picture. For references please visit http://antarea.org, http://cle.fourmis.free.fr and read Seifert - Ameisen Mittel und Nordeuropas. Lutra.

Comment: Your answers need to be backed up with some sources and explanations.

Comment: The issue is that most of the time, when identifying insects on bad pictures, there isn't any formal character available. Identifications are often based on the general aspect of the insect by a trained observer.